# Тревоги на сообщения в чате

Tags: поддержка, тревоги, чат

Историю тревог оставленных на сайта можно посмотреть в профиле:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/227049

Например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли посмотреть список тревог а также решения по ним принятые на сообщения в чатах?

Comment: нет это сделать нельзя.

Comment: @Grundy если это так, то выглядит как недоработка в системе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На MSE висит *feature request* об этом: [Can we get a Flag-History for chat's moderator attention flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264377/339911) Таким образом, упомянутого функционала пока нет. Всё, что могу предложить, это поддержать идею голосом или объявить конкурс для дальнейшего привлечения внимания. Я проголосовал "за".